# check registry values for multiple keys and export results into csv

Tags: powershell, registry

Here is what I am trying to do:

- Run script to verify the existence of 8 registry keys and the values set for those keys.
- Export the results to a CSV file for review.

Output should look like this:

PCname | RegKey | Value | Exists 0 or 1|

I have tried a number of different script options to return results using `Get-ItemProperty`, `Get-RegistryValue`, `Get-ItemPropertyValue` and have not gotten the results I'm looking for.

**Updated script**

```
$Computers = Get-Content -path "LocalPath\file.txt

$info = ForEach ($PC in $Computers) {
    #Check each key
    $regKeyPaths = Get-Content -path "localPath\file.txt"
    Write-Output "Computer name is: $PC"

    ForEach ($regKey in $regKeyPaths) {
    #check if key exists
    $pathExists = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC {Test-Path -Path $using:regKey}
    #if it exists get the key properties and values
    if ($pathExists){
        $properties = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC {Get-Item -Path $regKey | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property}
        $values = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC {foreach ($property in $properties) {
    Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $regKey -Name $property
    } }
    }

# if key doesnt exist, set properties/values to null

    else {
    $properties = $null
    $values = $null
    }

    # custom object

    [PSCustomObject]@{
    PCName = $PC
    RegKey = $regKey
    Property = $properties
    Value = $values
    Exists = $pathExists
    }
    }
    }

#export to .csv. Expanding 'property' and 'value'
$info | Select "PCName","RegKey",@{Name='Property';Expression={[string]::join(";", ($_.Property))}},
@{Name='Value';Expression={[string]::join(";", ($_.Value))}},'Exists' | Export-CSV "LocalPath\Ouput.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: First off, It looks like you are wanting to run it on remote computers but `Get-ItemProperty -Path 'RegistryPath' -ValueName "Value"` will just be running it locally on your machine. You need to use something like `Invoke-command -computer $pc {Get-Item-Property .....}`

Comment: So I tried the following script to see if the outcome changed:
```
$Computers = Get-Content "path\PCEnabled.txt"
foreach ($PC in $Computers) {
   Write-Host "Running against "$PC
   $value = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC -ScriptBlock {
   Get-ItemProperty -Path "RegKeyPath" -Name "Key" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
$value."Key" }
```
It did return a 1 value or no value at all (which I assume means it doesnt exist).  How would I export that to a csv with the above mentioned column headers?

Comment: `$Computers = Get-Content -path "LocalPath\file.txt` right after this line do. 
`Write-output $Computers`. It still sounds like $Computers doesn't have any data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to export the information that you want is by using a [PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3). This would allow us to save the information you want in the loop (PC name, registry key, if the key exists, any properties of the key, and the property values).

For each computer in the list we loop through the list of registry keys you want to check.If the key exists we get the key properties and values for the properties. That information is saved into the custom object.

`$info` will be an array of our custom objects, which we export to csv. I ended up having to expand the `propertiess` and `values` while exporting to csv, since those could be arrays if there are more than one property per key (separated by ';').

```
# list computers
$computers = @("MYPC1","MYPC2")
# list of KEYS you want to check
$regKeyPaths = @("REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Software\sub1","REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Software\sub2")



$info = ForEach ($PC in $Computers) {
    # check each key
    foreach ($regKey in $regKeyPaths) {
    # check if key exists 
    $pathExists  = Invoke-command -ComputerName $PC {Test-Path -Path $using:regKey}
    # if it exists get the key properties and the values
    if ($pathExists){
        $properties =  Invoke-command -ComputerName $PC {Get-Item -Path $regKey | Select-object -ExpandProperty Property}
        $values = Invoke-command -ComputerName $PC {foreach ($property in $properties){
          Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $regKey -Name $property
        } }
    }
    # if key doesn't exist set properties and values to null
    else{
        $properties= $null
        $values = $null
    }
    # custom object
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PCName = $PC
        RegKey = $regKey
        Property = $properties
        Value = $values
        Exists = $pathExists
    }
}
}
# export object to csv. Expanding "Property" and "Value"
# https://www.millersystems.com/powershell-exporting-multi-valued-attributes-via-export-csv-cmdlet/
$info | Select "PCName","RegKey",@{Name='Property';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.Property))}},
@{Name='Value';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.Value))}},'Exists' | Export-Csv  -Path info.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

##### output

[image: output]

Comment: I think that is right about what Im looking to get out of it!  Let me give it a try and will report back what it returns.  Thanks much!

Comment: So in order to look up multiple keys and output them all at the same time, would I need to put the registry paths into a text file and then save it as $regKeyPaths?

Comment: @MjrPayne you could save them to a text file and read from and then save it to a variable or directly to the script like in my example. You could do something like `$regKeyPaths = @(Get-Content -path c:\pathtotext.txt`. To read from a file and save it to an array, assuming one key path is on each line.

Comment: So I ran the updated script this morning and its throwing the following error:

"Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'.  The argument is null or empty.

That line reads:  $pathexists = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC {Test-Path -Path $using:regKey}

there is a foreach for $PC from $Computers which references a computer list .txt file.

Comment: @MjrPayne does `$PC` have a value? If you `write-output $PC` is it outputting anything. I updated the code, was missing two `invoke-command` in the version I pasted in.

Comment: So I have 2 reference files called out.  the first is a foreach for the machine names ($PC in $computers --> references list of computer names).  $regKeyPaths is a text file with the specific registry items that I am looking at.

Added in the Invoke-Commands and am still getting an error with 'computerName'.  I will update the script here shortly.

Comment: @MjrPayne is the script reading the the computer names? Your error earlier makes it seem there is an issue since it said  ` The argument is null or empty` in regards to the value for `$PC`. It's saying $PC has no value so maybe something is happening when you read in the values to `$computers`. If you add `Write-Output "COMPUTER NAME IS: $PC"` to the loop before the inner loop ` foreach ($regKey in $regKeyPaths)` do you see the computer name listed.

Comment: Just updated the initial post with the current script.  When I tried to inject the Write-Output, I got the following:

"Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

And then the additional errors with the failure to validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'